# Spotify API {'error': 'invalid_client'} Authorization Code Flow [400]

Tags: python, django, spotify

This is one of my many attempts at making a POST request to https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token.

Scope was set to 'playlist-modify-public, playlist-modify-private'.

I'm using Python 3.7, Django 2.1.3.

No matter what I do, response_data returns {'error': 'invalid_client'}

I've tried many things, including passing the client_id/client_secret inside the body of the request as per the [official Spotify documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/) for this particular request... to no avail.

Please help!

```
def callback(request):

    auth_token = request.GET.get('code')     # from the URL after user has clicked accept
    code_payload = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': str(auth_token),
        'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI,
    }

    auth_str = '{}:{}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
    b64_auth_str = base64.b64encode(auth_str.encode()).decode()

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Basic {}'.format(b64_auth_str)
    }

    post_request = requests.post(SPOTIFY_TOKEN_URL, data=code_payload, headers=headers)

    response_data = json.loads(post_request.text)
        # ==> {'error': 'invalid_client'}
```

Comment: Hello. Did you figure out how to solve?

Comment: Hey @MatteusBarbosa, I actually realized I had reset my Spotify client_secret on the Spotify Dashboard and completely forgot to modify my code accordingly... 
Felt real smart :|

Comment: thanks for your response

Answer (score 14):

From the documentation

> An alternative way to send the client id and secret is as request parameters (client_id and client_secret) in the POST body, instead of sending them base64-encoded in the header.

```
    SPOTIFY_TOKEN = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    request_body = {
        "grant_type": GRANT_TYPE,
        "code": code,
        "redirect_uri": REDIRECT_URI,
        "client_id": SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
        "client_secret": SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }
    r = requests.post(url=SPOTIFY_TOKEN, data=request_body)
    resp = r.json()
```

This works as well.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - the current accepted answer has exactly the same issue.

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you so much. I was using some parameters from the JavaScript example on the Spotify Developers site, and needed to omit them.

Answer (score 10):

I suspect the issue is with invalid characters in your `Authorization` header. Try using [`urlsafe_b64encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.urlsafe_b64encode) instead of `b64encode` to prepare that header value:

```
b64_auth_str = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(auth_str.encode()).decode()
```

Comment: I had the same error using:
hash = (client_id + ":" + client_secret).toString('base64');
So i encode it on this site : https://www.base64encode.org and it work

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-for-Developers/INVALID-CLIENT-Invalid-redirect-URI/td-p/5228936) is another problem mentioned. If the error is

```
INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI
```

then you need to register your URI. Quote from the source - to have everything at one place:

> Simply log in, find your app and click "Edit Settings" in the top right section. Under redirect URIs you add REDIRECT_URI and remember to click save in the bottom. This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is generate a new client secret via the spotify API dashboard. I ran into this error not too long ago and this resolved my issue.

Don't forget to reflect this changed client secret everywhere it is referenced in your code.