# Spotify API OAUTH2 Server Error Response when requesting token

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, fetch, spotify

[Spotify Oauth2 Docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow) - Client Credential Flow

I asked a similar question, and I was able to get the code running in google apps script (javascript). I am using Client Credential Flow. However, I tried to recreate this code in Nodejs. When running this code, I receive a server error.

```js
error: "server_error"
```

This is the problem code in Nodejs

```js
const defaultConfig = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
// this encodes the app_id and api_key into a base64 string like the documentation states 
    'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa(spotify.API_ID + ':' + spotify.API_KEY)}`
  },

  body: JSON.stringify({
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
  })
  };

// this function is wrapped in a list titled, "apiSettings" with other functions. I just included the authorization function here:
  const apiSettings = {
   getSpotifyAuthorizeToken: async () => {
const endpoint = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";
return await (await fetch(endpoint, defaultConfig)).json();
  },
};
```

I got this similar code to work in google apps script with no problems.

Could the server error be a result of me running Nodejs on a "localhost:xxxx"? The documentation states that, "The Client Credentials flow is used in server-to-server authentication."

if this is not the case, could you provide a working

Answer (score 0):

[Spotify API OAUTH2 Server Error Response when requesting token](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69411265/7108653)

From [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69393517/7108653), I would like to propose the following sample scripts.

#### Sample script 1:

If you want to convert the script of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69399865/7108653) to Node.js and node-fetch, how about the following script?

```js
const spotify = { API_ID: "API_ID", API_KEY: "API_KEY" }; // Please set your client ID and client secret.

const buf = Buffer.from(spotify.API_ID + ":" + spotify.API_KEY);
const para = new URLSearchParams();
para.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");
const defaultConfig = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { Authorization: `Basic ${buf.toString("base64")}` },
  body: para,
};
const apiSettings = {
  getSpotifyAuthorizeToken: async () => {
    const endpoint = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";
    return await (await fetch(endpoint, defaultConfig)).json();
  },
};
```

#### Sample script 2:

If you want to convert the script of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69400480/7108653) to Node.js and node-fetch, how about the following script?

```js
const spotify = { API_ID: "API_ID", API_KEY: "API_KEY" }; // Please set your client ID and client secret.

const para = new URLSearchParams();
para.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");
para.append("client_id", spotify.API_ID);
para.append("client_secret", spotify.API_KEY);
const defaultConfig = {
  method: "POST",
  body: para,
};
const apiSettings = {
  getSpotifyAuthorizeToken: async () => {
    const endpoint = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";
    return await (await fetch(endpoint, defaultConfig)).json();
  },
};
```

#### Reference:

- [node-fetch](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch)