# Error 'invalid_client' when using JavaScript and Spotify API with Ionic 6 and Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, spotify, ionic6

I'm encountering an issue while using JavaScript and the Spotify API in my Ionic 6 with Angular project. Here's the code snippet I'm using:

```
async function getToken() {
    const clientid = 'xxxxx';
    const clientsecret = 'xxxxx';
    const buf = new Buffer.from(`${clientid}:${clientsecret}`);

    const result = await fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': 'Basic' + buf.toString('base64')
        },
        body: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
    });

    const data = await result.json();
    return data;
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error: `"invalid_client"`. Can anyone provide some guidance on how to resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spotify API {'error': 'invalid\_client'} Authorization Code Flow \[400\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53567858/spotify-api-error-invalid-client-authorization-code-flow-400)

Comment: And what should the code variable be? Also, im getting another error:  requests is not defined. Sorry in quite new to this stuff. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: The problem was that the 'Basic' was missing a space, so its 'Basic '.